# Can I block non-national TLDs in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I get quite some spam in my mailbox from French sources. Blocking the sender under junk options is no use as they every time use a different e-mail address. I know I can block top level domains (TLDs), but much of the spam comes from the `ovh` TLD (ovh is a French ISP), and Outlook only seems to know about national TLDs.

Is there a way I can block non-national TLDs?

Comment: I tried that now, but the e-mail isn't being removed. Well, maybe the inbox isn't scanned for the changed list. Guess I'll have to wait and see. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use Rules. go to the Rules Wizard (Manage Rules), and choose

1. New Rule
2. Start from a blank rule -> Apply rule on message I recieve
3. Click Next
4. Then check `with specific words in the sender's address` and click the blue text (in the box under step 2)
5. Enter the text to be searched for
6. Click next
7. Choose what to do - Delete it, permanently delete it or move it (or other!)
8. Next
9. Next (unless you need to add an exception
10. Name it and run it! Click Finish

I think the above is a dangerous because it would block dave.ovhorio@email.com but, it may suffice!

You could try and right click any email, and choose junk -> junk email options. Form here, go to Blocked Senders tab and add .ovh . This also has the same issue as the above rule.

I'm sure the rule mentioned above would work, but in case not, you'd have to write a VBa script ... THIS IS NOT TESTED. Back up your emails first just incase!

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx _
                     (ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim itm As MailItem
    Dim m As Outlook.MailItem
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ns = Application.Session
    arr = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Set itm = ns.GetItemFromID(arr(i))
        If itm.Class = olMail Then
             Set m = itm
             If InStr(0, m.SenderEmailAddress, ".ovh", 1) Then
                 m.Delete
             End If
        End If
    Next
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set itm = Nothing
    Set m = Nothing
End Sub
```